# How get 2 queries Mongodb in single request using Angular and Node

Tags: mongodb, angular, request

I need to get 2 queries datasets to single(single request) site and display them in 2 separate divs. That should use REST API. 
Im using MEAN(Mongo,express,Angular,Node.js).

I dont know how should look that process.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read  the [**Asking help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a help

Comment: First of all, create a webservice to fetch data using express framework.
In webservice you can use mongoose to create and fetch multiple queries.
Join the result and return the data through API.

Comment: Thanks. I done it in 1000xxx try,.